# Ошибка: нарушение доступа для записи

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int Key;
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
};
class Tree {
public:
    Node* Top;
    Tree() {
        Top = NULL;
    }
    Node* GetTop() {
        return Top;
    }
    void Build(Node* x) {
        Node* T2 = new Node();
        x->Left = T2;
        x->Left->Key = 2;
    }
};
int main() {
    Tree T;
    T.Build(T.GetTop());
    cout << T.GetTop()->Left->Key;
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит ошибку на строке

```
x->Left = T2;
```

> Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.
>
> x было nullptr.
>
> Если для этого исключения имеется обработчик, выполнение программы
>   может быть продолжено безопасно.

Как исправить?

Comment: видимо нужно добавить проверку, что внутри функции Build параметр x может оказаться NULL и обрабатывать это случай особым образом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tree T;` - создаётся новый экземпляр класса `Tree`, при этом вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, в котором `Top` принимает значение `NULL`.

`T.Build(T.GetTop());` - сначала вызываем функцию `GetTop()`, которая возвращает `NULL` и передаем это значение в качестве аргумента функции `Build()`. Внутри этой функции переменная `x` имеет значение `NULL`, как только что мы выяснили. Вы используете `x->Left`, поэтому и получаете ошибку.